# Determine the position of node using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Given the following XML:

```
<data>
    <content>
        <section link-id="32">
            <entry id="9">
                <title handle="apples">Apples</title>
            </entry>
            <entry id="1">
                <title handle="oranges">Oranges</title>
            </entry>            
            <entry id="4">
                <title handle="pears">Pears</title>
            </entry>
        </section>
        <section link-id="23">
            <entry id="59">
                <title handle="chevrolet">Chevrolet</title>
            </entry>
            <entry id="31">
                <title handle="toyota">Toyota</title>
            </entry>            
            <entry id="54">
                <title handle="bmw">BMW</title>
            </entry>
        </section>
    </content>
</data>
```

Styled by this XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="data">
<html>
<body>

<xsl:apply-templates select="content/section" />      

</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content/section">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Title: <xsl:value-of select="entry/title"/>
        </li>   
        <li>
            Position: <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
        </li>               
    </ul>
</xsl:template>
```

How would I display and integer representing the order (1-6) of the selected `entry` nodes? The expected values would be 1 and 4. The example shows values of 1 and 2, i.e. the position in the selected node set. What I want is the numeric position in the XML file, not the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear exactly what you are asking about, as your "1 and 4" and reference to "position in the previous node set" is a bit confusing.  But I think you have a couple options.

You can process all entries from the start:

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="content/section/entry"/>
  </ul>
</body>
...
<xsl:template match="entry">
  <li>
    Title: <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    Position: <xsl:apply-templates select="position()"/>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you find you have to process the sections and entries separately, then you'll find yourself inside of an entry with `position()` not helping.  At this point you can use `<xsl:number level="any"/>`.  If you are at a position deep inside of an entry, you can use `<xsl:number count="entry" level="any"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing "position" (an English word that describes what you want) with "position()" (an XPath function that gives you something quite different).

Try

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry[1]">
  <xsl:number level="any" from="content"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It looks as if you are deliberately using the XSLT 1.0 "feature" whereby `xsl:value-of` applied to a node-set ignores all nodes except the first. If you want your code to be compatible with 2.0 (and understandable to the reader) it's best to make this explicit by writing `select="entry[1]/title"`.